# Sql syntax to Trim alphanumeric data in mysql phpmyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Is there any syntax query in mysql phpmyadmin to trim alphanumeric(varchar) data? Here's how I want it to happen:

In my table i have two fields id(int) and promocode(varchar)(25), inside my promocode column I have this sample data `BEFKR679GKQTX46AFKP14VY` composed of (25) ...and i want it to trim the first **12** alphanumeric only, making it look like these `BEFKR679GKQT`.. and I don't know how to change the existing 1,000 inputted data in my table.. into all 12 not 25.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Back up your tables. If you can't do this, don't continue.
2. Test a command like on a test table and make sure you understand it:

   ```
   UPDATE my_table SET promocode = SUBSTRING(promocode,1,12);
   ```
3. When it works you your satisfaction on test tables, and your back up is complete, do it to the real table.

More info on MySQL string functions is here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

Running SQL from phpMyAdmin is here:

http://community.mybb.com/thread-4720.html